# FATAL EXCEPTION: PID: 30982 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo when testing app in an actual phone

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create two activities with the second one starting after sometime of the first starting.
When I launch the app on an emulator, it runs correctly but when I test it on my phone (TECNO L8 android API22) it begins launching the first activity then crushes with the following error message on the logcat:

```
    01-13 10:54:23.276 30982-30982/com.otemainc.smartmenu E/AndroidRuntime: 
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.otemainc.smartmenu, PID: 30982
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.otemainc.smartmenu/com.otemainc.smartmenu.activity.Splash}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                        at com.otemainc.smartmenu.activity.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:15)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6167)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                        at com.otemainc.smartmenu.activity.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:15) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6167) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
                                                                     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.otemainc.smartmenu:drawable/restaurant" (7f06006a)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06006a a=-1 r=0x7f06006a}
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2776)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2700)
                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                                                                        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3791)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:533)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:529)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:525)
                                                                        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:419)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                        at com.otemainc.smartmenu.activity.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:15) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6167) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
    01-13 10:54:23.370 30982-30982/com.otemainc.smartmenu I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30982 SIG: 9
```

Here is my Splash.java

```
    package com.otemainc.smartmenu.activity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import com.otemainc.smartmenu.R;

    public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    Thread delay = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    delay.start();
}
```

}

Note: Testing this on an emulator runs as expected
      Testing it on an actual phone has it crushing and logging the above error message

Here is my activity_spalsh.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.otemainc.smartmenu.activity.Splash"
    android:background="@drawable/restaurant">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TxtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="52sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.547" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImgLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCopyright"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle"
    android:text="@string/rights"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tXTPowered"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_rectangle"
    android:text="@string/poweredby"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

And this is my activity_login.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="18dp"
   android:paddingRight="18dp"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.otemainc.smartmenu.activity.Login"
   android:background="@drawable/restaurant">
   <!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_person_white_24dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#f9d7db" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_vpn_key_white_24dp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#f9d7db" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Remember me "
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/btn_login"
            android:text="Log in"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:padding="16dp"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_lock_open_white_24dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forget password? "
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As earlier explained, the crushing only occurs when I test the app on an actual device but does not occur on any emulator(I am using nexus 10).

Comment: Share your XML.

Comment: Which one, activity_splash, activity_login or Android manifest?

Comment: activity_splash.xml

Comment: I have edited to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `LinearLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout` in your `activity_spalsh.xml`. This may solve your problem.

And also check the background you are using named `restaurant` also exists in `Drawable` folder

---

***Update:***
Try to use these `xml` instead of yours, just to see that if it can fix your crushing problem.

**1.**`activity_spalsh.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Splash Activity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvExVin" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**2.**`activity_spalsh.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Log In Activity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvExVin" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The bacground does exist

Comment: Still crushing on actual device